# Flagging a team has a typo in the description

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

I tried flagging a team.

[image]

I believe that the description should be

> This *team* exists *solely* to promote a product...

Just a quick typo :)

Comment: Nobody *really* pronounces that second "l" anyway...

Comment: Also inconsistent capitalisation of 'Team'.

Comment: Also the wording of the offensive option is inconsistent with the main site: "Rude or abusive" on main, "Offensive or abusive" on Teams. Should made consistent IMO..

Comment: nitpick: there isn't a period in the end of `offensive or abusive` but the others do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I committed a typo fix that sorts this soley.